# Not allowing to post an answer with error Body cannot contain

Tags: discussion, support, bug

I was trying to post an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36588246/mapping-an-array-of-jquery-objects-not-working), while the system started to bombard me with error messages saying `Body cannot contain <starting few words of the answer>`, whatever I tried the same error started coming

[image: Sample 1]

[image: Sample 2]

In sample 2, I tried with a text that was already accepted in the previous answer, even that was not allowed.

[image: Sample 3]

Is this a new validation that was added to the system?

---

The complete answer that I wanted to post is something like

The problem is [.map()](https://api.jquery.com/map) will flatten the array returned from the callback method. A solution to this is to wrap the array with another one as given below

You can also read the text of the `firstChild` of the `li` element to get the first part of the inner array as given below

```js
function getData() {
  var sourceData = $("#source").find("li");
  return sourceData.map(function(i, item) {
    return [
      [$(item.firstChild).text().trim().slice(0, -1), $(item).find("b").text()]
    ];
  }).get();
}

var data = getData();
$('pre').text(JSON.stringify(data))
console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="source">
  <li>北京空气质量：<b>90</b>
  </li>
  <li>上海空气质量：<b>70</b>
  </li>
  <li>天津空气质量：<b>80</b>
  </li>
  <li>广州空气质量：<b>50</b>
  </li>
  <li>深圳空气质量：<b>40</b>
  </li>
  <li>福州空气质量：<b>32</b>
  </li>
  <li>成都空气质量：<b>90</b>
  </li>
</ul>

<pre></pre>
```

Comment: I guess it just gets caught on one special word or so. But it's weird that even if you write something different it can't contain the start from your answer.

Comment: I tried a lot of stuff, like `The problem is .map() will flatten`, `jQuery .map() will flatten` etc and of course `is there anything that will allow me to post it` :(

Comment: I think it would be safe to add the `bug` tag to this one...

Comment: Because your trying to put in content like: `成都空气质`.. it thinks it's spam, or something. Why it doesn't for the question? Who knows.

Comment: Well, that's interesting.